# Would setting up phpList and Codeigniter on the same server make conflicts?

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, vhosts, phplist

So I have both phpList and a Codeigniter project setup in the same ssh server.

On my `/etc/httpd/conf.d/phplist.conf`, I have this vhost setting:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName phplist.example.com
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/phplist-3.0.5/public_html

    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/phplist_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/phplist_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The database setting on my ci-test is:

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => '*server ip address*',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'root@999',
    'database' => 'listingapp_db',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

And the config setting has:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://server-ip-address/citest/';

$config['index_page'] = '';
```

When I try to visit both projects in the web, the phpList site works fine, but my Codeigniter project on the other hand gives me an error of:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /citest/ was not found on this server.
```

Did the project have conflicts regarding access? How can I access my ci-test?

Comment: Where is your CI installation on disk?

Comment: @Don'tPanic It's located in /var/www on the server

Comment: And do you want your phpList to be separate from your CI install?  I mean you have it set up as `phplist.example.com`, do you want CI accessible at that hostname, or will you have it on a separate host like `citest.example.com` or something?